# Formula $n=\sum_{d|n,b\geq1}\phi(d)$ where $\phi$ is euler phi function

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

**Proof:**
Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$. Then for each subgroup $C$, $gen(C)$ is the set of generators of $C$. Then $G$ is disjoint union $\cup_C{gen(C)}$. If $|C|=d$ then we know that $C$ has exactly $\phi(d)$ generators. Thus $n=|G|=\sum_{C<G}|gen(C)|=\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)$

**Example:**
$G_{12}=\{e,a,a^2,\dots,a^{11}\},G_6=\{e,a^2,a^4,a^6,a^8,a^{10}\},G_4=\{e,a^3,a^6,a^9\},G_3=\{e,a^4,a^8\},G_2=\{e,a^6\},G_1=\{e\}$ Hence $gen(G_{12})=\{a,a^5,a^7,a^{11}\}$,
$gen(G_{6})=\{a^2,a^{10}\}$,
$gen(G_{4})=\{a^3,a^9\}$,
$gen(G_{3})=\{a^4,a^8\}$,
$gen(G_{2})=\{a^6\}$,
$gen(G_{1})=\{e\}$(How to derive these???)

**My questions:**
(1) How to determine the generator of a cyclic group? Why they are not generated by a single element $<a>$? Why is G a disjoint union of these generated sets since obviously these subgroups are not disjoint?

(2) Why does every subgroup of order $d$ has exactly $\phi(d)$ generators? It's said to follow from Lemma(1) $G=<a>,O(a)=n\implies O(a)=\frac{n}{gcd(m,n)}$; Lemma(2) $C=<a^{n/d}>$ for all subgroup $C<G$ that has order $d$ and $G$ has order n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss some important points from Lemma 2 that is

> $G$ has a unique subgroup $d$ of order $n$ for every divisor $d$ of n whch can be generated by an element of order $n/d$.

Try to check whether this is included in your reference. Also, from Lemma 1, we can know another fact that is

> $\langle a \rangle=\langle a^{m}\rangle\iff |a|=|a^{m}|\iff n=\frac{n}{(m,n)}\iff (m,n)=1$.

So for a cyclic group of order $n$, the number of its generators is the number of integer which is coprime to $n$, that is the Euler's phi function, $\phi(n)$. Hence, a cyclic group may not generated by an unique element. Also, $G=\cup_Cgen(C)$ means the set of generators for each cyclic subgroup is disjoint, since a generator cannot generate two cyclic subgroup of different order.

For your example, $G_{12}=\langle a\rangle$,$G_6=\langle a^2\rangle$,$G_4=\langle a^3\rangle$,$G_3=\langle a^4\rangle$,$G_2=\langle a^6\rangle$, $G_1=\langle e\rangle$
Take $G_6$ as example. It is cyclic group of order $6$. So there is $\phi(6)=2$ generators of $G_6$. And to find the generators of $G_6$, you just have to find all the elements of order $m$ where $(m,n)=(m,12)=2$.

Comment: how to explain $\#\{m:<a>=<a^m>\}=\#\{m:(m,n)=1\}=\infty$

Answer (score 0):

- answer to 1) 
  A cyclic group $G$ has by definition a generator $g$. Let $1<d<n$ then $g^d$ generates a cyclic subgroup of $G$, the order $r$ of this group is by definition the order of $g^d$. From $g^{rd} = 1$ we conclude that $rd = 0 \operatorname{mod} n$. Now either $\operatorname{gcd}(d,n) = 1$ so $r = n$ and $g^d$ is another generator of $G$. On the other hand if $\operatorname{gcd}(d,n) > 1$  $\exists s$,  such that $s\operatorname{gcd}(d,n) = n$ giving $r=s$ and $g^d$ generatres a proper subgroup. The subgroups intersect indeed, but the subsets of their generators do not. You can see this partition as related to the equivalence relation "generates the same subgroup as".
- answer to 2) Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $d$ with generator $h$. As we have seen previously $h^e$ is also a generator $\iff \operatorname{gcd}(d,e) = 1$, this value is the definition of $Euler's $ totient function.