# How to derive generator of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The examples are from [Formula $n=\sum_{d|n,b\geq1}\phi(d)$ where $\phi$ is euler phi function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001240/formula-n-sum-dn-b-geq1-phid-where-phi-is-euler-phi-function) but they weren't the focus of that question

---

**Question:** Give the generating sets of below cyclic groups: $G_{12}=\{e,a,a^2,\dots,a^{11}\},G_6=\{e,a^2,a^4,a^6,a^8,a^{10}\},G_4=\{e,a^3,a^6,a^9\},G_3=\{e,a^4,a^8\},G_2=\{e,a^6\},G_1=\{e\}$

**Answer:**
$gen(G_{12})=\{a,a^5,a^7,a^{11}\}$
$gen(G_{6})=\{a^2,a^{10}\}$,
$gen(G_{4})=\{a^3,a^9\}$,
$gen(G_{3})=\{a^4,a^8\}$,
$gen(G_{2})=\{a^6\}$,
$gen(G_{1})=\{e\}$

Can someone fill in the steps to find the elements that generates the cyclic groups? For example how can $a^5$ generates $G_{12}$? (however it's easy to see at least the base element and its inverse can be counted as generators)

Comment: an element $x\in \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is a unit if and only if $x$ is coprime to $m$

Comment: @AlanWang I don' think so since it wasn't really the focus of that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, consider $(a^5)^n$ gives $a^5,a^{10},a^{15}=a^3,\dots$ that finally reaches every element

Answer (score 0):

In a finite cyclic group $G = \{g,g^2, \dots, g^{n-1}, g^n\}$ where $g^n = e$, the order of an element is given by

$$o(g^k) = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}.$$

So you're looking for those elements of power $k$ coprime to $n$. Also, when you have examples like $G_6$, you can replace $a^2$ by $b$.